# To have keyboard viewer in Debian?

Tags: debian, gnome, usability, keyboard-viewer

Another name for the *keyboard viewer* is the *special characters keyboard viewer* developed first in OSX, Youtube video [here](https://youtu.be/TNePcJe6xCc?t=1m8s). 
It is used to visualise the dynamics of typing different key combinations in first-level/second-level/... ways.

**Warning**
I do not want to have virtual keyboard like shown by the confused answers in the thread [Onscreen keyboard? (like OSX's Keyboard Viewer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59767/onscreen-keyboard-like-osxs-keyboard-viewer) where the title is about *Onscreen keyboard viewer*, not virtual keyboard. 
I tested Florence/Onboard/xvkbd/... but the virtual keyboard is risky because it can misconfigure your keyboard settings, forcing you restart your system, so no to virtual keyboards.

You can view static keyboard viewer by *Language menu* at top > *Show Keyboard Layout* > Output, or from the settings, *Region & Language* > select an input source > click on the keyboard button in the lower-right-hand corner; this will display the keyboard layout in Fig. 1. This view is static, *i.e.* it displays all accessible characters at once; it does react to key-presses, but only by highlighting the depressed key(s). It would be easier to understand the layout if it showed the characters accessible with the current set of modifiers: *e.g.* the <kbd>P</kbd> keycap would show only <kbd>p</kbd> by default, and would would change to <kbd>P</kbd> if you pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>ö</kbd> (on a Dvorak layout) if you pressed <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, and <kbd>Ö</kbd> if you pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

In OS X, the feature has been 5-10 years, but I have not found anything builtin in any Linux distro nor any program in `apt` by the following searches.

```
apt search viewer | grep keyboard
```

I think Gnome 3.22 can support such a tool in Linux. 
I need the tool to better visualise how to typo A with dots/... (ä, ö, ...) in Linux.

Fig. 1 Static keyboard layout of Dvorak, an example, 
Fig. 2 Example of dynamic keyboard viewer in OS X ([source](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os-x-using-the-keyboard-viewer)) but video [here](https://youtu.be/TNePcJe6xCc?t=1m8s)

[image]
[image]

OS: Debian 9
Gnome: 3.22

Comment: Could you explain what the OSX viewer has that the Gnome viewer doesn't? And what you mean by “static” and “dynamic”? I don't understand why you find it easier to see how to type `ä` with the OSX viewer than with the Gnome viewer. How do you do it with OSX? How do you do it with GNome?

Comment: @Gilles Please, see the Youtube video about the wanted viewer in Debian.

Comment: If you are using Gnome (or at least gtk) this can be an answer to your question:
https://askubuntu.com/a/459997

Comment: @user259905 that’s just the GNOME key map, which is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The GNOME key map shows the available characters, albeit not dynamically. For example, the four symbols on the <kbd>Q</kbd> key in your screenshot indicate that

- <kbd>Q</kbd> on its own produces “q” (the lower-left symbol)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> produces “Q“ (the upper-left symbol)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> produces “ä” (the lower-right symbol)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> produces “Ä” (the upper-right symbol)

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> is also known as <kbd>Alt R</kbd> (the right-hand <kbd>Alt</kbd>), and in your screenshot, “Level 3 Select”.

Comment: I added a video in the body to better explain what I want.

Comment: I understand what you want, I don’t think it exists (and I agree it would be useful).

Comment: If you understand what Léo wants, could you edit the question? I have no idea why the Gnome viewer isn't a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Gilles done, hopefully that’s clearer...

Comment: Which package provides this software? I use Xubuntu, so I don’t have GNOME packages installed by default.

Comment: @Melebius it’s part of `gnome-control-center`.

Answer (score 4):

The OS X Keyboard Viewer does two things:

1. shows which key you are pressing (primarily useful for finding which physical key corresponds to a particular mac modifier key when you're not using a Mac keyboard), though if your keyboard layout doesn't match the mac one or you've remapped keys by some other method, you'll still need trial and error to find a particular mac modifier.)
2. changes to show you what each key produces when you hold down a modifier key without having to use trial-and-error

On linux desktops, xev will do the former, by showing what key you press or release while its window has the focus.  That's only a partial substitute the OS X keyboard viewer, but may help until someone builds a full substitute.